At what point is the best to switch instruction language to the target language
Somewhere I've read the recommendation that one should strive to use the target language as much as possible preferably exclusively, but I guess that doesn't work optimally from day one. Yes, for your first language you didn't have much of a choice, but then it took you a year before you even learned your first word.
So at which (CEFR) level is the best to start using the target language as instruction language?
With "target language" I mean the language one is trying to learn and "instruction language" is the language used to explain new words, grammatical concepts and so on.

There are at least ten language teaching methods.
The one in the OP's question is called The Direct Method

When using the Direct Method of language teaching, all teaching
happens in the target language, forcing the learner to think and speak
in that language. The learner does not use their native language in
the classroom at all!
As a result, students work out key grammar concepts by practicing the
language and by building up their exposure to it. Standard classroom
techniques for this approach include Q+As, conversation, reading
aloud, writing and student self-correction.
[...]
It’s worth noting that none of these teaching strategies should be
considered “the best” since every language classroom, educator and
student is different. In this blog post, we are looking at these
teaching approaches mainly from the perspective of traditional
face-to-face classroom teaching instead of including also all of the
aspects and characteristics of online language teaching. How to become
a language teacher online and which language teaching methods work the
best when teaching online are separate topics that we try to answer in
our other blog posts. Our advice is rather that educators should try
different teaching methods out, tailoring them to their specific
context and reviewing the impact they have.
Keep also in mind that these strategies can be adapted and combined in
various ways to suit different learners, contexts, and educational
goals. The most effective language teaching approach is often a mix of
several strategies tailored to the needs of individual learners.

10 best language teaching strategies
How fast one progresses in learning a language depends on the individual.
There is no sure-fire way to predict this.

Based on my own experience, the level at which you can start teaching in the target language efficiently depends on several factors, including the distance between the native language and the target language, the age of the learners, and possibly the number of hours of instruction per week.
For example, I went to school in Flanders, where the official language is Dutch, and when I started learning English in the third year of secondary school (age 14), the instruction was in English from the start. This was feasible because everybody's native language was Dutch (another Germanic language), we had three hours of English per week and English morphology is simple.
However, one year later we also started learning German, which is closer to Dutch than German, but instruction was mostly in Dutch. We had only one hour of German per week and German morphology is much more complex than English (especially the case system). At university, both German linguistics and German literature were taught in German, but this switch was not difficult.
For French, with which we started in the penultimate year of primary school (age 10), instruction was in Dutch at primary school, but switched to French in secondary school.
When I took up Spanish in the last year of university, instruction was exclusively in Spanish from the start, even though most students could not be expected to have learnt any Spanish before the start of the course. However, everybody already knew French, which helps to some extent.
When I started learning Standard Chinese in adult education, instruction was initially in Dutch. This was not because teaching in Chinese was entirely unfeasible but because, as the teacher explained, it was difficult to take in three hours of Chinese in an evening when you are just starting out and it would have made progress less efficient. For example, explaining what stroke order is and the basics of grammar are explained much more efficiently in the learner's language than in the target language. We would have had a native speaker as a teacher in the third year (but circumstances prevented that and we first had a native speaker in the fifth year).
If anything can be extrapolated from this, it is that there is no one-size-fits-all solution. You can start in the target language if that language is in the same language family and possibly if it has very simple morphology. In all other cases, trying to do this would make progress slower until learners have reached a level when they can talk about language itself.

As many aren't familar with the Dutch school system I think your answer would be more useful if you instead used your age instead of which year of which school. Also note that it was not question when it's possible - we've all done it for at least one language. Some indication on how fast you progressed in the languages would shed som light on the matter.
